# How does one validate a dojo javascript form for Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, validation

I'm trying to validate a form written in Javascript/Dojo before posting it using Ajax.  Here's the code:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
                dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
                dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
        </script>
        <script>

        function send()
        {
            var mainForm = dojo.byId( "mainform" );
            dojo.connect( mainForm , "onsubmit", function( event )
            {
                dojo.stopEvent(event);
                if ( mainForm.validate() )
                {
                    alert( "valid" );
                    var xhrArgs = {
                            form:  dojo.byId( "mainform" ),
                            load:  function( data )
                            {
                                // Success
                                alert( "Success" );
                            },
                            error:  function( error )
                            {
                                // Error
                                alert( "Error" );
                            }
                        }
                    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost( xhrArgs );
                }
                else
                {
                    alert( "not valid" );
                }
                });
        }
        dojo.addOnLoad( send );
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <h2>Invitation:</h2>
    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Form" id="mainform" jsId="mainform" encType="multipart/form-data" action="whatever.php" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:  </label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="50"
                    dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                    required="true"
                    propercase="true"/>
                    <br><br>

        <button type="submit" dojoType="dijit.form.Button">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Obviously I'm not using "alert"s in the production code; they help show me what's working and what's not working.  The problem here is that the call to mainForm.validate() never returns.  Commenting out the call to validate() "fixes" the problem (the form data is POSTed to the .php file), but now there's no validation at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.

Make sure that you are using `dijit.byId` to find dijits (as opposed to just their DOM nodes with `dojo.byId`), and that you are using properly cased event names. Try changing your `send` function like so:

```
function send()
{
    var mainForm = dijit.byId( "mainform" );
    dojo.connect( mainForm , "onSubmit", function( event )
    ....
```

When you use `dojo.byId` you get a regular DOM node (the regular HTML `<form>` tag), and not the actual dijit object (which has the `validate` function). This is also why improperly case on "onsubmit" works: a regular HTML form has an event called "onsubmit", but the dijit only has a method "onSubmit" (I agree this is a bit confusing).

Answer (score 0):

Its a pie cake. do like this.
dijit.form.Form has a attr called state. if this state is empty string then the form widgets like **dojo textbox** are valid.

You can do like this.
1) Don't attach onsubmit for the form. Instead just attach click for the button and do the following code inside the button click handler.

```
var validForm = "";
dojo.connect( submitBtnDojoWidget, "onclick", function( event ){
 if(mainform.state === validForm){
  mainform.submit();
 }
 else {
  // here mainform.state may be 'invalid' or 'incomplete'
  console.log(mainform.state);
 }
})
```